# Google Vision OCR Multiple Text Detection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm triying to multiple language text detection with google cloud vision. But I have a problem. 
If I send the request text detection api endpoint this url;

```
https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=XxxXX
```

and this body;

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "image_url"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 1
        }
      ],
      "ImageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "tr", "en"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the this error code;

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"image_context\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
            "fieldViolations": [
                {
                    "field": "requests[0]",
                    "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"image_context\" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

What is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the field `"ImageContext"`, it should be `"imageContext"` with lower-case "i".

Comment: I want to kill myself :( You are right. It's working now. Thank you :)

Comment: Great! Glad that it is working! Please accept the answer if it helped you. :)